# onmouseover not showing div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table, mouseover

I have a table in my DB which I call to show everything in that table on a page one of the items in the table is an image which when moused over needs to show a popup showing data from a separate table which corresponds to that item. I have a JQuery which calls the data depending on the row from the 1st table but when I try to actually put the two together I get the first table showing fine but now I get no pop up on mouseover.

This page is currently included in the index.php page which has the scripts to call the .js / .css files.

Here's the code for what I am trying to do:

```
     <html>




  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class="center2">
  <tr>
  <td width='60'><img src="images/box_tl.png"></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_tm.png)" align="center"><img src="images/news.png"></td>
  <td width='25'><img src="images/box_tr.png"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_ml.png)"><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_mm.png)">


 <?php
include 'connect.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_img") or die(mysql_error());;

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width'90%' id='1' class='tablesorter'><thead>";
echo "<tr> <th> </th> <th>Mob Name</th> <th>Id</th> <th>Health</th> <th>Body</th> <th>Effects</th> <th>Spawn</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {

 $mob_id = $row['mob_id'];
 $mob = $row['mob'];
 $body = $row['body'];
$mob_name = $row['mob_name'];
 $health = $row['health'];
 $level = $row['level'];

// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>";
echo "<img src='/testarea/include/mobs/$mob' />";
echo "</td><td>";
echo $mob_name;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $level;
echo "</td><td>";
echo $health;
echo "</td><td>";
echo 


"
<a onmouseover='popup($('#hidden-table').html(), 400);' href='somewhere.html'><img src='/testarea/include/mobs/dead/$body' /></a>
";

echo "

<div id='hidden-table' style='display:none;'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='center3'>
  <tr>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_tl.png'></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_tm.png)' align='center'></td>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_tr.png'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_ml.png)'><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_mm.png)'>
";




$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_drop WHERE mob_name='$mob_name'") or die(mysql_error());;

echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' width='250' id='2' class='tablesorter'><thead>";
 echo "<tr> <th> </th> <th>Item Name</th> <th>Qty</th></thead><tbody>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {

$id = $row['id'];
$item_img = $row['item_img'];
$qty = $row['qty'];
$item_name = $row['item_name'];


// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td width='50'>";
echo "<img src='/testarea/item/$item_img' />";
echo "</td><td width='150'>";
echo $item_name;
echo "</td><td width='50'>";
echo $qty;
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";


echo "
  </td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_mr.png)'><h2>.</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_bl.png'></td>
  <td style='background: url(images/info_bm.png)' align='center'><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td width='14'><img src='images/info_br.png'></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>"




;
echo "</td><td>";
echo "test";
echo "</td><td>";
echo "test";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";

?>




  </td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_mr.png)"><h2>.</h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width='60'><img src="images/box_bl.png"></td>
  <td style="background: url(images/box_bm.png)" align="center"><h2>.</h2></td>
  <td width='25'><img src="images/box_br.png"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```

Comment: "; in the begin of your last code block is a typo?

Comment: no, all 3 blocks of code are all just one block, ive just seperated them to show where the problem is

Comment: if i use: echo include ('info2.php'); instead of the middle block of text to call the middle block then i get the pop up i want but this causes the image not to show and the 1st table to only show the 1st row

Comment: Well what you have on the line 48 of the mobs_darn.php file?

Comment: ive updated the main question with new code

Answer (score 0):

you have two semi-colons on this line...could be the problem

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_drop WHERE mob_name='$mob_name'") or die(mysql_error());;
```

Comment: removing the extra semi-colon seems to make no difference, ive updated the main question with new code so maybe gives better idea now